# Converse.js: How to display fullname from vCard in chatbox

Tags: xmpp, converse.js

I am using [converse.js](https://conversejs.org/) library to create XMPP client, but I can't figure out how to display user's full name (if have) from vCard instead of username in chatbox.

Is there some simple configuration solution, or I need to write custom plugin for it?

Answer (score 1):

If the user has their full name set in a VCard it will automatically be set on their chat box as soon as the VCard has been fetched.

You can get it via `converse.chats.open(jid).get('fullname')`.

UPDATE: in versions 3.0.0 and above, you need to register a plugin, and then in the plugin you can get it via:

`_converse.api.chats.open(jid).get('fullname')`

This happens asynchronously, so you might run into timing issues whereby you try to get the fullname before the VCard has been returned.

If you are writing your own custom view which you want to update automatically as stuff gets set, then you'll have to write a plugin so that you can have access to the underlying ChatBox Backbone.Model and can add an event listener for `fullname`.